# Android BluetoothGatt setCharacteristicNotification only setting first characteristic

Tags: android, bluetooth, gatt

I have been having trouble using two different characteristics at the same time through the same Bluetooth LE device. It only registers the first characteristic and not the second one. If I switch them around, it still registers the first in line, but not the second. Both the first and second characteristic need to be registered and received. If it helps, I am using a Samsung Galaxy S4 running 4.4.2.

Here is the section of the code that calls setCharacteristicNotification()

```
if (mBluetoothBeaconGatt != null && mBluetoothBeaconGatt.getService(UUID_CUSTOM_SERVICE) != null) {

        characteristicBracelet = mBluetoothBeaconGatt.getService(UUID_CUSTOM_SERVICE)
                .getCharacteristic(UUID_CUSTOM_BRACELET);

        characteristicBeacon = mBluetoothBeaconGatt.getService(UUID_CUSTOM_SERVICE)
                .getCharacteristic(UUID_CUSTOM_BEACON);

        if(characteristicBracelet != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Init Bracelet Characteristics");
            this.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristicBracelet,
                    true);
        }
        if(characteristicBeacon != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Init Beacon Characteristics");
            this.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristicBeacon, true);
        }
    }
```

setCharacteristicNotification

```
if (UUID_CUSTOM_BEACON.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
        if (mBluetoothBeaconGatt != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Enabling indication for beacon");
            mBluetoothBeaconGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);
            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic
                    .getDescriptor(UUID
                            .fromString(CustomGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));
            descriptor
                    .setValue((enabled) ? BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE
                            : BluetoothGattDescriptor.DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            mBluetoothBeaconGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
        }
    } else if (UUID_CUSTOM_BRACELET.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
        if (mBluetoothBraceletGatt != null || mBluetoothBeaconGatt != null) {
            BluetoothGatt gatt = (mBluetoothBeaconGatt != null) ? mBluetoothBeaconGatt : mBluetoothBraceletGatt;
            gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);
            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic
                    .getDescriptor(UUID
                            .fromString(CustomGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));
            descriptor
                    .setValue((enabled) ? BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE
                            : BluetoothGattDescriptor.DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
        }
    }
```

The variables that get tested to see if they are null verify them as being not null.

If you need other information or this is a duplicate, please let me know.

Thanks for taking time to help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't perform multiple bluetooth operations at the same time. Once you get a `onDescriptorWrite`, you can enable/disable your next characteristic:

```
private int index;
private boolean enabled;

private BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
        index++;
        setNotification();
    }
}

public void notify(boolean enabled){
    index = 0;
    this.enabled = enabled;
    setNotification();
}

private void setNotification(){
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic;
    switch(index){
        case 0:
            characteristic = mBluetoothGatt.getService(MY_SERVICE_UUID)
                        .getCharacteristic(UUID_CUSTOM_BRACELET);
            break;
        case 1:
            characteristic = mBluetoothGatt.getService(MY_SERVICE_UUID)
                        .getCharacteristic(UUID_CUSTOM_BEACON);
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);
    BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG);
    descriptor.setValue((enabled) ? BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE
                        : BluetoothGattDescriptor.DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
    mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(desc);
}
```

Nice tutorial from NewCircle: https://newcircle.com/s/post/1553/bluetooth_smart_le_android_tutorial

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing with the multiple `BluetoothGatt` objects.